# Floating point number answer difference between c++ and calculator

Tags: c++

I am calculating a floating point number by formula: number=1/(n-2.001)
Where n is any integer from 1 to infinite.
But it give me different answer in laptop and scientific calculator.

```
C++ calculation : 0.333444
Calculator answer: 0.3334444815
```

I have to get all digits in c++. How i get this.

Comment: What data type do you use?

Comment: How do you display the output? Please include all relevant code.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: Another example, similar to Ninja's but slightly different:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116

Answer (score 1):

Decimal equivalent of 1/3 is 0.33333333333333….

An infinite length number would require infinite memory to store, and we typically have 4 or 8 bytes. Therefore, Floating point numbers store only a certain number of significant digits, and the rest are lost.

> **NOTE :** When outputting floating point numbers, cout has a **default precision** of 6 and it truncates anything after that.

*The **precision** of a floating point number defines how many significant digits it can represent without information loss.*

- Therefore in your case only 6 decimals points are outputted and rest are turncated
- To change the Precision of floating-point data types in C++ check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)