# "Double" is not printing more than 6 significant digits even after setprecision

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm self learning C++ and for some reason "double" doesn't print more than 6 significant digits even after std::setprecision. Do I need to do something else? Most recent version of codeblocks if that helps. This is all the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::setprecision(9);
    double A = 654321.987;
    cout << A << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that 123456e10 123.456 and 123456e-10 all have _6 significant digits_.  `654321.987` has 9.

Comment: Try something fun like `setprecision(15)`.  That's guaranteed to print 6 significant digits.

Comment: Tactical note: Code::Blocks is a tool that sits atop a separate C++ compiler, so often saying "Most recent Code::Blocks" conveys minimal information. It could be sitting atop an ancient compiler. It could be sitting atop the most recent pull from trunk. On Windows some packages of Code::blocks ship with a mingw-GCC toolchain, and I believe the most-recent official release ships with GCC 8.1. The Cool kids are using GCC 11.1. I'm not so cool, so I'm still using GCC 10.2. And 6.3. And 4.8. And 3.3.

Comment: Yeah. I'm still rocking a 20-year old compiler for one product that just wont die. Frankly I see that as a win.

Comment: Somewhat related:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to feed the result of `std::setprecision(9)` to `std::cout`. Otherwise it has no way of knowing what output stream it applies to (and so it won't apply to anything).

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << A << std::endl;
```

Or if you prefer you can do it separately:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(9);
std::cout << A << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes a lot more sense doing it this way.

Comment: I noticed the link in your profile does not work anymore and the correct one seems to be https://keith-s-thompson.github.io