# C++ , Why the "double" data type is showing only 7 digits and not 15-16?

Tags: c++, structured-programming

I'm new to c++ and i want to represent a value as accurately as possible using "double" data type , why pi & area values aren't represented fully here ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcE10.png)

expected that float and double will have different value representations in my code but they are showing the same accuracy with different size

Here is the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const double PI = 3.14159265359;
    int radius = 6;
    cout << "Since radius is " << radius << " Cm" << '\n';
    cout << "and pi is " << PI << '\n';
    double area = PI * radius;
    cout << "Then the Area of the circle will equal (pi x radius)= " << area << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, post text, not images of code.  Second, you are relying what the default behavior of 
 `std::cout` is showing you.  That is not how to determine what the real internal values are.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68293886/double-is-not-printing-more-than-6-significant-digits-even-after-setprecision)

Comment: Apologies , here is the code but i believe writing it here will be kind of messy 

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
const double PI=3.14159265359;
int radius=6;
cout<<"Since radius is "<<radius<<" Cm"<<'\n';
cout<<"and pi is "<<PI<<'\n';
double area=PI*radius;
cout<<"Then the Area of the circle will equal (pi x radius)= "<<area<<'\n';
 return 0;
}

what should i do to get the desired output in this case ?

Comment: @MrasksAlot — re: “it will be messy” — indeed. Edit the **question** to add the code.

Comment: By default, stream inserters for floating point types show six digits. Read about [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) if you need help making the code less messy when you edit it into your question.

Comment: Yup this answers my question .. thank you guys
Edited the code format in the question , appreciate your patience guys
i will read more about std::setprecision and utilize it

Comment: To easily form a code block and keep your indentation type ``` press enter paste code exactly as it is in your IDE. Press Enter. Type ``` and press enter again. See the edit I made to the question.