# Precision problem with multiplying float values C++

Tags: c++, precision, multiplication

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    float P_a2, P_b2,result2,x,y,z;

    cout << "P_a(x)= 9,09*x^9– 9,09*x^3+ 9,09*x\n";
    cout << "P_b(x)= – 8980,032*x^6– 186,34*x^4– 649,23*x^2\n\n";

    x = 1.2;

    cout << "\n";

    y = x * x * x * x * x * x;

    P_a2 = ((9.09 * y - 9.09) * x * x + 9.09) * x;

    cout << setprecision(9) << P_a2 << "\n\n";


    z = x * x;

    P_b2 = ((-8980.032 * z - 186.34) * z - 649.23) * z;
    
    cout << setprecision(9) << P_b2 << "\n\n";
    result2 = P_a2 * P_b2;
    cout <<fixed<< setprecision(15) << result2 << "\n\n"; //prints -1184587.00000000

   
    //right answer is -1 184 586,9806370984
    
}
```

Is this problem related with type of the value?
I really cant understand why it happens and what should i do...
Can somebody please explain why does it happens with result2 and can i avoid it without changing the type?

P.S my bad, i've forgot to add the minus, right answer ofc is
-1 184 586,9806370984

P.P.S yes, i know that this code can be optimized, but our teacher said us to do so.
And yes parentheses are correct.

I know i can fix it by using double, i'm just asking if i can solve this problem without using it

Comment: Probably going to come down to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You seem to ask for a high precision result (for example the `setprecision(15)` argument), but you are using `float` type which can only encode 7 decimals. Use `double` values.

Comment: If you use double you get better results, still, for such levels of precision these are not what you shoud use.

Comment: No, you can't 'solve' it without using a bigger precision. The precision of each intermediate result of every multiplication and addition your program performs is limited by the length of the floating-point values representation.

Comment: You can check the precision of the floating point type, q.v.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116

Comment: Then could you show more details about the acceptance criteria for "solving" the problem. 1) Does that mean using 2 or 3 floating point variables to hold different part of the result? 2) Does that mean we can rearrange P_a2 * P_b2 into different combination of terms? 3) What class are you taking and in which chapter, so that may indicate the kind of approaches or mindset one should take.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues (not c++ issues, more of general floating point numerical calculation issues):

1. float type is usually 6-7 decimal digits precision, using double would give you 15-16 decimal digits, more helpful for the problem. Seems like you need more digits than `float` to at least hold the result.
2. There is a subtraction in P_a, so should watch for [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) when grouping the terms.