# C++ Why is it not possible to use all the range of floating point numbers?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, precision

I am trying to understand up to which point I can add or substract floating point numbers that are very far apart (e.g. 3.34e-20 + 1.22) with a correct answer.  I ran this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>

int main(){
    std::cout.precision(30);

    float small_f = 3.34e-20;
    float large_f = 1.22;
    float sum_f = small_f + large_f;
    std::cout<<"float: Minimum normalized value: "<< FLT_MIN <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"float: small = "<< small_f <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"float: large = "<< large_f <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"float: sum = "<< small_f << "+" << large_f << " = " << sum_f <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"float: (sum*2.0 - 1.22*2.0)/2.0 = "<< (sum_f*2.0-1.22*2.0)/2.0 <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"float: (sum*2.0 - large*2.0)/2.0 = "<< (sum_f*2.0-large_f*2.0)/2.0 <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    long double small_ld = 3.34e-20;
    long double large_ld = 1.22;
    long double sum_ld = small_ld + large_ld;
    std::cout<<"long double: Minimum normalized value: "<< LDBL_MIN <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"long double: small = "<< small_ld <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"long double: large = "<< large_ld <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"long double: sum = "<< small_ld << "+" << large_ld << " = " << sum_ld <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"long double: (sum*2.0 - 1.22*2.0)/2.0 = "<< (sum_ld*2.0-1.22*2.0)/2.0 <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"long double: (sum*2.0 - large*2.0)/2.0 = "<< (sum_ld*2.0-large_ld*2.0)/2.0 <<std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Ouput:

```
float: Minimum normalized value: 1.17549435082228750796873653722e-38
float: small = 3.3399998940068452799152744128e-20
float: large = 1.2200000286102294921875
float: sum = 3.3399998940068452799152744128e-20+1.2200000286102294921875 = 1.2200000286102294921875
float: (sum*2.0 - 1.22*2.0)/2.0 = 2.86102295188328525910037569702e-08
float: (sum*2.0 - large*2.0)/2.0 = 0

long double: Minimum normalized value: 3.36210314311209350626267781732e-4932
long double: small = 3.3400000000000001388033392343e-20
long double: large = 1.219999999999999973354647409
long double: sum = 3.3400000000000001388033392343e-20+1.219999999999999973354647409 = 1.219999999999999973354647409
long double: (sum*2.0 - 1.22*2.0)/2.0 = 0
long double: (sum*2.0 - large*2.0)/2.0 = 0
```

I don't understand why I can't obtain the correct answer, even for the float type, because all the values of the computations are higher than the minimum normalized value (~1e-38).

Comment: Do you know what *precision* means? What happens if you add 0.00001 to 1 and display the result to *only* 2 decimal places?

Comment: Not all binary values can be represented as decimals in a "precise" way,  that's all.

Comment: Notice (programmers') floating point numbers are not (mathematicians') real numbers.

Comment: @rturrado not to mention what these mean for physicians

Comment: @AdrianMole 1.00 I guess.

Comment: @rturrado: Floating-point numbers are real numbers; each floating-point datum other than a NaN or infinity is a real number. Floating-point arithmetic is not real-number arithmetic; the sum, product, or other result of a floating-point operation is not generally the same as the result of the corresponding real-number-arithmetic operation. Using the model that it is arithmetic that approximates, not numbers, is essential for analyzing, designing, and debugging floating-point software.

Comment: You are exceeding the number of decimal digits of precision.  q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116

Comment: the last non-zero digit to the right must be zero, or it is not an exact float; so you started out w/ a problem