Confusion about outputting floating point values using cout
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    float floatname = 0.123456789;
    double doublename = 0.123456789;

    cout << "float = " << floatname << endl;
    cout << "double = " << doublename << endl;

    return 0;
}

Output is:
float = 0.123457
double = 0.123457

What has happened to the 6 in both cases?
I tried using setprecision() but the penultimate number is still missing.

works fine

The penultimate number is not missing.  The number was rounded to 6 digits, and ...6789 rounds to 7.  A single-precision float can only hold 6 (sometimes 7) decimal digits to begin with.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Going after endl and not the relative include? One that I’m guessing is a rough approximation of the bits include.

Als you might find this interesting (and funny) : Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile. Side note : #include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"  the moment you have to use a relative path in your includes, something is usually wrong : in this case use #include <iostream>  (at least that IS a standard include file)

setprecision should certainly affect the number that you see with double. Can you post the code that used setprecision and still didn't work.

You will probably want to check the precision supported by each type.  q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116
